# explain why this.age is not modfiying the global variable age?

Tags: javascript

i dont know why this.age is not modifying the global variable age.. Can you explain it??

```
var age = 24;
function local() {
  /*var age = 10;
    console.log("this is local age : "+age);
    age = 0;
    console.log("this is new local age : "+age);
  */
  this.age = 2;
  //console.log("this is another local age : "+age);
}
local();
console.log(age);
```

Comment: the code as it stands DOES modify the global variable age - at least, in a browser - because `this` is `window`, and `var age` is equivalent to saying `window.age`

Comment: If `console.log(age)` outputs `24`, then the code isn't evaluated in the global scope. Some JavaScript environments wrap the contents of a script file in a closure to isolate their effects from other files. In such cases, `var age` is a local variable rather than global.

Comment: Some sampling tools have options that will also wrap the code you input in a `function`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), for example, has "Load Types" of `onLoad` (currently the default) and `onDomReady` that behave this way (also why the alternatives are named `No wrap`).

Answer (score 0):

Change like below.

```
window.age = 24; // earlier, var age  = 24;
window.age = 2; // earlier, this.age = 2;
```